# Jison not assuming correct grammar

Tags: javascript, parsing, parser-generator, jison

I'm creating a grammar in jison

This is my jison file:

> sgr.jison

```
/*
AUX VARIABLES
*/
%{
var contratos = "(E1:ENTIDADE)-[C:CONTRATO] -> (E2:ENTIDADE)";
var dataArray = {};

function
translateQuery(dataArray) 
{
    var finalQuery = dataArray["Listar"] + " "
                     + dataArray["Contratos"] + "\n"
                     + dataArray["Onde"] + " "
                     + dataArray["condition"] + "\n"
                     + dataArray["Retornar"] + " "
                     + dataArray["returnAttributes"]
    console.log("\n" + finalQuery)
}

%}


/* description: Parses end executes mathematical expressions. */

/* lexical grammar */
%lex

%%
\s+                     /* skip whitespace */
Listar                  return 'MATCH'
Contratos               return 'CONTRACTS'
Onde                    return 'WHERE'
Retornar                return 'RETURN'
e                       return 'AND'
ou                      return 'OR'

","                     return 'DELIMITER'
";"                     return 'END'

[><>=<==]               return 'MATH_SYMBOL'
[0-9]+\b                return 'VALUE'
[A-Za-z0-9.]+\b         return 'ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE'
["]                     return 'QUOTATION_MARK'






/lex

%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */

expressions :
    regra               
        {
            /*
            ADD SOMETHING 
            ONLY IF NEEDED
            */
        }
    | /* | significa um OU o que quer dizer que isto aqui pode ter mais do que uma regra ISTO E FEITO PELA RECURSIVIDADE*/
    expressions regra
        {
            /*
            ADD SOMETHING 
            ONLY IF NEEDED
            */
        }
;

 regra: 
    MATCH CONTRACTS
    WHERE condition
    RETURN returnAttributes END
        {
            $$ = $1 + " "
                + $2 + " "
                + $3 + " "
                + $4 + " "
                + $5 + " "
                + $6 + " "
                dataArray[$1] = "MATCH"
                dataArray[$2] = contratos
                dataArray[$3] = "WHERE"
                dataArray["condition"] = $4
                dataArray[$5] = "RETURN"
                dataArray["returnAttributes"] = $6
                /*ESTA FUNCAO TRATA DE TRADUZIR A QUERY QUE E INTERPRETADA*/
                translateQuery(dataArray)
        }
 ;

 condition:
    ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE MATH_SYMBOL
        {
            $$ = $1 +  " "
                + $2
        }
    |
    condition VALUE
        {
            $$ = $1 +  " "
                + $2
        }
    |
    condition QUOTATION_MARK ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE QUOTATION_MARK
        {
                $$ = $1 +  " "
                + $2 + " "
                + $3 + " "
                + $4
        }
    |
    condition AND ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE MATH_SYMBOL VALUE
        {
            $$ = $1 +  " "
                + $2 + " "
                + $3 + " "
                + $4 + " "
                + $5
        }
    |
    condition OR ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE MATH_SYMBOL VALUE
        {
            $$ = $1 +  " "
                + $2 + " "
                + $3 + " "
                + $4 + " "
                + $5
        }
    |
    condition AND ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE MATH_SYMBOL QUOTATION_MARK ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE QUOTATION_MARK
        {
            $$ = $1 +  " "
                + $2 + " "
                + $3 + " "
                + $4 + " "
                + $5 + " "
                + $6 + " "
                + $7
        }
    |
    condition OR ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE MATH_SYMBOL QUOTATION_MARK ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE QUOTATION_MARK
        {
            $$ = $1 +  " "
                + $2 + " "
                + $3 + " "
                + $4 + " "
                + $5 + " "
                + $6 + " "
                + $7
        }
 ;

 returnAttributes:
    ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE
        {
            $$ = $1
        }
    |
    returnAttributes DELIMITER ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE
        {
            $$ = $1 + ""
                + $2 + " "
                + $3
        }
 ;
```

In my **lexical grammar** definition i have:

```
e     return 'AND'
ou    return 'OR'
```

so, whenever in my testfile "e" or "ou" were found they should return "AND" and "OR" respectively.

The problem is, when i test it, instead of returning me "AND" and "OR" it is returning me "e" and "ou".

Take a look:

This is my testfile:

> test.sgr

```
Listar Contratos
Onde C.preco=1000
Retornar C.Preco, C.NifAdjudicante,C.NifAdjudicataria;


Listar Contratos
Onde C.preco=1000 e E1.name="ESTG"
Retornar C.Preco, C.NifAdjudicante,C.NifAdjudicataria;


Listar Contratos
Onde C.preco=1000 e E1.name="ESTG" e C.TipoProcedimento="ADS"
Retornar C.Preco, C.NifAdjudicante,C.NifAdjudicataria;


Listar Contratos
Onde E1.name="ESTG"
Retornar E1.name,C.Preco,C.NifAdjudicante,C.NifAdjudicataria;


Listar Contratos
Onde E1.name="ESTG" e C.preco=1000 ou C.preco>1000 
Retornar E1.name,C.Preco,C.NifAdjudicante,C.NifAdjudicataria;
```

The outputs should be:

```
MATCH (E1:ENTIDADE)-[C:CONTRATO] -> (E2:ENTIDADE)
WHERE C.preco = 1000
RETURN C.Preco, C.NifAdjudicante, C.NifAdjudicataria

MATCH (E1:ENTIDADE)-[C:CONTRATO] -> (E2:ENTIDADE)
WHERE C.preco = 1000 AND E1.name = " ESTG "
RETURN C.Preco, C.NifAdjudicante, C.NifAdjudicataria

MATCH (E1:ENTIDADE)-[C:CONTRATO] -> (E2:ENTIDADE)
WHERE C.preco = 1000 AND E1.name = " ESTG " AND C.TipoProcedimento = " ADS "
RETURN C.Preco, C.NifAdjudicante, C.NifAdjudicataria

MATCH (E1:ENTIDADE)-[C:CONTRATO] -> (E2:ENTIDADE)
WHERE E1.name = " ESTG "
RETURN E1.name, C.Preco, C.NifAdjudicante, C.NifAdjudicataria

MATCH (E1:ENTIDADE)-[C:CONTRATO] -> (E2:ENTIDADE)
WHERE E1.name = " ESTG " AND C.preco = 1000 OR C.preco > 1000
RETURN E1.name, C.Preco, C.NifAdjudicante, C.NifAdjudicataria
```

However the outputs are:

[image: outputs]

What i've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens identified in your lexical analyser have a *token type*, which is the string you return from the scanner action, and the matched text, which the lexical scanner keeps in its `yytext` property from which the parser initializes the token's semantic value. (This is not very well described by the documentation.)

So in this action:

```
condition:
    condition OR ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE MATH_SYMBOL VALUE
        {
            $$ = $1 +  " "
               + $2 + " "
               + $3 + " "
               + $4 + " "
               + $5
        }
```

the value of `$2` is the text matched by the token whose token type was `"OR"`, which is `ou`. If you wanted the string `"OR"`, that's what you should have placed into the action:

```
condition:
    condition OR ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE MATH_SYMBOL VALUE
        {
            $$ = $1 + " OR "
               + $3 + " "
               + $4 + " "
               + $5
        }
```

(Having said that, I have to say that I think there are better ways of structuring an AST. But if this one works for you, that's cool.)